# Azure - hostheader not accepting host without the www

Tags: azure

I have set up my hostheader in the service definintion file as follows:

```
<Site name="Example" physicalDirectory="..\example.WebUx">
 <Bindings>
   <Binding name="Example" endpointName="HttpIn" hostHeader="www.example.com" />
 </Bindings>
</Site>
```

When I enter www.example.com it goes to the correct web site in my role. However when I enter just example.com without the www then it goes to the default web. I tried the following and it didn't help:

```
<Site name="Example" physicalDirectory="..\Example.WebUx">
 <Bindings>
   <Binding name="Example" endpointName="HttpIn" hostHeader="www.example.com" />
   <Binding name="Example" endpointName="HttpIn" hostHeader="example.com" />
 </Bindings>
</Site>
```

I tried the following and it came up with an error message "Error   1   Found duplicate site elements defined with same virtual path 'Example/' for role Default.WebUx

```
<Site name="Example" physicalDirectory="..\Example.WebUx">
 <Bindings>
   <Binding name="Example" endpointName="HttpIn" hostHeader="www.example.com" />
 </Bindings>
</Site>
<Site name="Example" physicalDirectory="..\Example.WebUx">
 <Bindings>
   <Binding name="Example" endpointName="HttpIn" hostHeader="example.com" />
 </Bindings>
</Site>
```

I tried just the following and it didn't work. When implemented this way both the www.example.com and example.com went to the default web.

```
<Site name="Example" physicalDirectory="..\Example.WebUx">
 <Bindings>
   <Binding name="Example" endpointName="HttpIn" hostHeader="example.com" />
 </Bindings>
</Site>
```

I'm running out of ideas :-(  Does anyone have experience of setting up the hostHeader so that it can accept both the www and non-www versions of my web sites.

Thanks

Here's some links that I also checked. Unfortunately they don't seem to help

[Link 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg433110.aspx)

[Link 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg557553.aspx#Sites)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you will get a domain to work with the Azure DNS.

I may be a bit out of date, but I believe the way to get Azure DNS to work is through CNAME - and CNAME works on subdomains, not on domains

Comment: Actually reading your question - maybe I have got this wrong - would be fascinated to see more about your setup - I'm off to readup some more...

Answer (score 2):

looks like your binding name attribute is the same.

```
<Site name="Xxx" physicalDirectory="..\Xxx.WebUx">
 <Bindings>

   <Binding name="Xxx" endpointName="HttpIn" hostHeader="www.xxx.com" />

   <Binding name="THE_NEXT_NAME" endpointName="HttpIn" hostHeader="xxx.com" />

 </Bindings>
</Site>
```

Comment: This seems to be the only response that answers the actual question!

Answer (score 0):

For a top-level domain, you have to add an A record pointing to the Virtual IP of your hosted service.  This is the same for all your web role instances.  However, this is pretty volatile, as your VIP will change if you delete your deployment.

I have not testing top-level domains with multiple sites in a web role, so not sure if you will still run into host header issues beyond this solution.  But the above will work for a web role hosting a single site.